# Keep sizes proportion between image views for different screens

Tags: android

In my application I have a layout with 3 image views with different heights (apple, wine, fish), bottom aligned. The layout height is constant. This layout looks good on hdpi screens, but I want to use the same images on mdpi. The problem is that on mdpi some of the image views might be down scaled and the proportion between the image views won't be the same. So, if the wine is down scaled, the apple might be tall as the wine bottle. What is the best way to avoid this? I thought about setting the same height for the images (the largest height), at run time. Then, they will all be scaled, and the proportion will be kept. Is this posible. I hope this is clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Just set:

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

on each of the ImageViews. They'll resize to fit proportionally no matter what the height.

EDIT: To clarify the weighting issue, let's say you have the three images (fish, apple, bottle), we'll call them F, A, and B.

Let's say we know that:

> F should be 2x as tall as A.
>  A
>   should be half as tall as B.

So we know that F should be the same height as B, while A should be half the height of B. We can give F and B equal weights (1), and A a weight of half (0.5). To simplify, we can multiply by 2 to give integers, so F and B have a weight of 2, A has a weight of 1. This way, no matter what height you set the LinearLayout to be, the images should remain proportional to each other.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:src="@drawable/fish"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/apple"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:src="@drawable/bottle"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I believe this is what you're asking for, but I may be mistaken still.

Comment: The thing is that if an image view get's down scaled, I want the others to scale down too, and the proportion between each other to be the same. If one of them has the height 200 an another 50, and if the first is scaled to 100, the other one must be scaled to 25. In this way the "apple" is still smaller than a "bottle".

Comment: Creating an image with  all 3 images, at run time, and using only one image view, with that composed image, instead of 3, could be a solution. But I don't know how to do this yet.

Comment: Try using the layout_weight attribute. Put the three ImageViews into a LinearLayout, and give them each a specific weight (e.g. if the bottle should be twice as large as the apple, give the bottle a weight of 2, the apple a weight of 1).

Comment: Set all the ImageView heights to fill_parent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't work. Maybe I wasn't clear. It's about the images, and not the image views. When one image get's scaled, another must be scaled too, with the same proportion. That's why, I think that creating a big image with all 3 images would be a solution. In this way, when a tall image must be scaled, the whole composed image will be scaled, including the small images.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your time! Maybe I was a little unclear. Sorry for that. The images are horizontally aligned and are added at run time. The "half of the first image" was just an example. In fact, the images can have any heights, so it's much harder to calculate the weights. Still, I don't think this example would work. If the F image is too wide it would be down scaled. So the height is going to be smaller too. What I want to happen is that image A should be down scaled too. This for your example. In my case if one image is too tall the  others must be down scaled too (horizontal orientation)

Comment: Ah okay, I think I get it now. So in your case, let's say your images are in a LinearLayout. You could get the height of the LL (call it lHeight), and the height of the original Bitmap (bHeight), and if bHeight > lHeight, calculate lHeight/bHeight to get your scaling percentage. Do this for each image to be inserted to find which image will have to be scaled down most. Then you can just apply this resizing before placing them into the LinearLayout. Your idea about using a composite image may be easier, depending on the situation, though.